# Precompiling Asp.net MVC views on TFS Build definition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We currently run builds on TFS. Is it possible to precompile views during TFS builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to pre-compiling the Asp.net MVC views on TFS.

You need to [Extend the Visual Studio Build Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process), introduce a new **BuildViews** target that will only execute if the **MvcBuildViews** property is set to true.

```
<Target Name="BuildViews" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Message Importance="normal" Text="Precompiling views" />
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Reference below article, refer to it for more information:

[Turn on Compile-time View Checking for ASP.NET MVC Projects in TFS Build 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jimlamb/2010/04/20/turn-on-compile-time-view-checking-for-asp-net-mvc-projects-in-tfs-build-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

MvcBuildViews ran into some errors caused by some stray web.config files in the obj folder when running a TFS build, and I managed to fix this issue by instead using PrecompileBeforePublish.

The following code will do so, only for a TFS build, if you add it to the correct `PropertyGroup`.

```
<MvcBuildViews Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)'=='true'">false</MvcBuildViews>
<PrecompileBeforePublish Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)'=='true'">true</PrecompileBeforePublish>
```

I found the solution on the following [website](https://exceptionshub.com/allowdefinitionmachinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-only-after-a-previous-build.html), which also gives the following warning:

> [PrecompileBeforePublish] is only supported by the “new” Web Publishing Pipeline stack (VS2010 SP1 + Azure SDK or VS2012 RTM). If you’re using VS2010 RTM, you’ll need use one of the alternative methods.